# Generating Swagger for one service only with Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

Is it possible to get the Swagger for an individual endpoint from Swashbuckle? I would like to be able to build individual Swagger documents from each endpoint in my API solution, rather than including all operations in all endpoints.